# How to run Java Swing application on raspberry pi

Tags: java, swing, raspberry-pi

I am trying to run Java swing application on raspberry pi (Model B revision 2) using Putty console. however when I run the command

```
java -jar myjar.jar
```

it throws exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.awt.HeadlessException:
No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it.
    at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:207)
    at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:536)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:420)
    at javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:225)
    ...............
```

I used to set display level as

```
export DISPLAY=:0.0
```

however it did not work. Readed all related SO posts however did not came to solution. please help me.

Comment: do other applications work ? Is X installed ? Give `xterm` or others a try

Comment: I am new to Raspberry Pi, dont know all terms however i have installed Xming on my machine. I am using Putty

Answer (score 1):

As you wrote you want to have the raspberry run a program and send its output to your window manager XMing on your Windows PC.

Because of this you need to tell on which PC you want the display, your current setup tries to display on the raspberry.

```
export DISPLAY=nameofwindowspc:0.0
```

Replace `nameofwindowspc` with the name of your PC or its IP address. More information about X and the variable can be found on the web, for example here: http://www.hungry.com/~jamie/xexport.html

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.awt.AWTError: Can't connect to X11 window server using 'myPCIP:0.0' as the value of the DISPLAY  variable.